# Load website's content through python

Tags: python, load

How can i load a specific content from a website through python?For example,i want to load some posts of a blog and appear them to my own site.How can i do this?

Comment: Is there a use to this other than to build a scraper? You also want to improve on your acceptance ratio.

Answer (score 4):

An answer:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def fetchtags(req, name, attrs, num):
        try:
            website = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print 'A problem occured. Please try again.'
            return
        soup = BeautifulSoup(website,
                             convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
        tags = soup.findAll(name=name,
                            attrs=attrs,
                            limit=num)
        return tags
```

Then you can use it like:

```
fetchtags('http://www.website.com', 'div', {'class':'c'}, 10)
```

To get 10 divs of class c from the specified url...

See Beautiful Soup for more details on the returned object.

Answer (score 2):

`urllib` and `urllib2` will let you load the raw HTML. HTML parsers such as BeautifulSoup and lxml will let you parse the raw HTML so you can get at the sections you care about. Template engines such as Mako, Cheetah, etc. will let you generate HTML so that you can have web pages to display.

Comment: yes i know how to generate html code but i want python automatically load the content to my website.Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. You just have to tell it how.

Comment: can you send me any link or code in order to help me more in this subject?